# Why does dataweave transform not display xml root element names?

Tags: xml, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

I am trying to define an xml metadata type for the DataWeave Transform component in Anypoint Studio (using Mulesoft 3.7). However, I cannot select a Root Element Name as nothing shows up in the drop-down. e.g. This is what I see when I try and define the metadata type:

[image: Define Type]

Here is the XML I am using as my example. I have tried with XSD as well and don't see the Root Element their either.

```
<eConnect xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    <RMCustomerMasterType>
        <eConnectProcessInfo>
        </eConnectProcessInfo>
        <taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd>
            <CUSTNMBR>JEFF0002</CUSTNMBR>
            <CUSTNAME>JL Lawn Care Service</CUSTNAME>
            <UpdateIfExists>1</UpdateIfExists>
        </taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd>
    </RMCustomerMasterType>
</eConnect>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to restart your Anypoint Studio and try again.

I tried to replicate your example in my computer and I also encountered same problem as your, no XML root element selected. But now its working after restarting my Anypoint Studio.

Comment: No clue as to why but this fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the xml configuration is correct and also it is better if you store the example file in the resources folder in your project rather than in C drive.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it. It works well for me.

[image]

Can you double check if the example file contains the XML? I'm also using Mulesoft 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried ur example, its works well & showing root elements.
try to save your file as eXtensible Markup Language file(*.xml,*.xaml).

Answer (score 0):

If your markup is invalid i.e adding or removing nodes or contains extra characters, it will not show root element .I faced same issue when I am working on transform message.Make sure your markup is clean.